# angular Reactive form group error not able to access the group element

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

angular Reactive form group error not able to access the group element.
angular Reactive form group error not able to access the group element.
angular Reactive form group error not able to access the group element. 
angular Reactive form group error not able to access the group element. 
angular Reactive form group error not able to access the group element. 
angular Reactive form group error not able to access the group element.

```
  <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" [formGroup]="myReactiveForm">

    <div fromGroupName="userDetails">

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="username">username*</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="username"  placeholder="username">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">            
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter email" formControlName="email">   
      </div>

      <small class="text-danger" *ngIf="!myReactiveForm.get('userDetails.email').valid && myReactiveForm.get('userDetails.email').touched">
        enter corrent email
      </small>         



    <button  type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

  </form>
```

ts

```
export class ReavtiveComponent implements OnInit {


  myReactiveForm : FormGroup

  ngOnInit() {

      this.myReactiveForm = new  FormGroup({

      'userDetails' : new FormGroup({

        'username': new FormControl(null,Validators.required),
        'email' : new FormControl(null,[Validators.required,Validators.email]),

      }),
      'course' : new FormControl('HTML'),
      'gender' : new FormControl('female')

    });
  }

  submiited=false;

    onSubmit(){
      this.submiited=true;
      console.log(this.myReactiveForm);
    }





ReavtiveComponent.html:5 ERROR Error: Cannot find control with name: 'username'
    at _throwError (forms.js:3357)
    at setUpControl (forms.js:3181)
    at FormGroupDirective.addControl (forms.js:7345)
    at FormControlName._setUpControl (forms.js:8070)
    at FormControlName.ngOnChanges (forms.js:7993)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:31906)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:44367)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:44306)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:45328)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:45271)





View_ReavtiveComponent_0 @ ReavtiveComponent.html:5
proxyClass @ compiler.js:19671
logError @ core.js:45546
handleError @ core.js:6066
(anonymous) @ core.js:41058
invoke @ zone-evergreen.js:359
run @ zone-evergreen.js:124
runOutsideAngular @ core.js:39572
tick @ core.js:41055
_loadComponent @ core.js:41096
bootstrap @ core.js:41019
(anonymous) @ core.js:40619
_moduleDoBootstrap @ core.js:40615
(anonymous) @ core.js:40570
invoke @ zone-evergreen.js:359
onInvoke @ core.js:39699
invoke @ zone-evergreen.js:358
run @ zone-evergreen.js:124
(anonymous) @ zone-evergreen.js:855
invokeTask @ zone-evergreen.js:391
onInvokeTask @ core.js:39680
invokeTask @ zone-evergreen.js:390
runTask @ zone-evergreen.js:168
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone-evergreen.js:559
Promise.then (async)
scheduleMicroTask @ zone-evergreen.js:542
scheduleTask @ zone-evergreen.js:381
scheduleTask @ zone-evergreen.js:211
scheduleMicroTask @ zone-evergreen.js:231
scheduleResolveOrReject @ zone-evergreen.js:845
then @ zone-evergreen.js:955
bootstrapModule @ core.js:40600
./src/main.ts @ main.ts:11
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:79
0 @ main.ts:12
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:79
checkDeferredModules @ bootstrap:45
webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap:32
(anonymous) @ main.js:1
ReavtiveComponent.html:5 ERROR CONTEXT DebugContext_ {view: {…}, nodeIndex: 6, nodeDef: {…}, elDef: {…}, elView: {…}}
View_ReavtiveComponent_0 @ ReavtiveComponent.html:5
proxyClass @ compiler.js:19671
logError @ core.js:45546
handleError @ core.js:6071
(anonymous) @ core.js:41058
invoke @ zone-evergreen.js:359
run @ zone-evergreen.js:124
runOutsideAngular @ core.js:39572
tick @ core.js:41055
_loadComponent @ core.js:41096
bootstrap @ core.js:41019
(anonymous) @ core.js:40619
_moduleDoBootstrap @ core.js:40615
(anonymous) @ core.js:40570
invoke @ zone-evergreen.js:359
onInvoke @ core.js:39699
invoke @ zone-evergreen.js:358
run @ zone-evergreen.js:124
(anonymous) @ zone-evergreen.js:855
invokeTask @ zone-evergreen.js:391
onInvokeTask @ core.js:39680
invokeTask @ zone-evergreen.js:390
runTask @ zone-evergreen.js:168
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone-evergreen.js:559
Promise.then (async)
scheduleMicroTask @ zone-evergreen.js:542
scheduleTask @ zone-evergreen.js:381
scheduleTask @ zone-evergreen.js:211
scheduleMicroTask @ zone-evergreen.js:231
scheduleResolveOrReject @ zone-evergreen.js:845
then @ zone-evergreen.js:955
bootstrapModule @ core.js:40600
./src/main.ts @ main.ts:11
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:79
0 @ main.ts:12
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:79
checkDeferredModules @ bootstrap:45
webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap:32
(anonymous) @ main.js:1
core.js:38781 Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
ReavtiveComponent.html:11 ERROR Error: Cannot find control with name: 'email'
    at _throwError (forms.js:3357)
    at setUpControl (forms.js:3181)
    at FormGroupDirective.addControl (forms.js:7345)
    at FormControlName._setUpControl (forms.js:8070)
    at FormControlName.ngOnChanges (forms.js:7993)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:31906)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:44367)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:44306)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:45328)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:45271)
View_ReavtiveComponent_0 @ ReavtiveComponent.html:11
proxyClass @ compiler.js:19671
logError @ core.js:45546
handleError @ core.js:6066
(anonymous) @ core.js:41058
invoke @ zone-evergreen.js:359
run @ zone-evergreen.js:124
runOutsideAngular @ core.js:39572
tick @ core.js:41055
(anonymous) @ core.js:40893
invoke @ zone-evergreen.js:359
onInvoke @ core.js:39699
invoke @ zone-evergreen.js:358
run @ zone-evergreen.js:124
run @ core.js:39511
next @ core.js:40890
schedulerFn @ core.js:35336
__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:185
next @ Subscriber.js:124
_next @ Subscriber.js:72
next @ Subscriber.js:49
next @ Subject.js:39
emit @ core.js:35298
checkStable @ core.js:39642
onHasTask @ core.js:39719
hasTask @ zone-evergreen.js:411
_updateTaskCount @ zone-evergreen.js:431
_updateTaskCount @ zone-evergreen.js:264
runTask @ zone-evergreen.js:185
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone-evergreen.js:559
Promise.then (async)
scheduleMicroTask @ zone-evergreen.js:542
scheduleTask @ zone-evergreen.js:381
scheduleTask @ zone-evergreen.js:211
scheduleMicroTask @ zone-evergreen.js:231
scheduleResolveOrReject @ zone-evergreen.js:845
then @ zone-evergreen.js:955
bootstrapModule @ core.js:40600
./src/main.ts @ main.ts:11
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:79
0 @ main.ts:12
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:79
checkDeferredModules @ bootstrap:45
webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap:32
(anonymous) @ main.js:1
ReavtiveComponent.html:11 ERROR CONTEXT DebugContext_ {view: {…}, nodeIndex: 16, nodeDef: {…}, elDef: {…}, elView: {…}}
View_ReavtiveComponent_0 @ ReavtiveComponent.html:11
proxyClass @ compiler.js:19671
logError @ core.js:45546
handleError @ core.js:6071
(anonymous) @ core.js:41058
invoke @ zone-evergreen.js:359
run @ zone-evergreen.js:124
runOutsideAngular @ core.js:39572
tick @ core.js:41055
(anonymous) @ core.js:40893
invoke @ zone-evergreen.js:359
onInvoke @ core.js:39699
invoke @ zone-evergreen.js:358
run @ zone-evergreen.js:124
run @ core.js:39511
next @ core.js:40890
schedulerFn @ core.js:35336
__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:185
next @ Subscriber.js:124
_next @ Subscriber.js:72
next @ Subscriber.js:49
next @ Subject.js:39
emit @ core.js:35298
checkStable @ core.js:39642
onHasTask @ core.js:39719
hasTask @ zone-evergreen.js:411
_updateTaskCount @ zone-evergreen.js:431
_updateTaskCount @ zone-evergreen.js:264
runTask @ zone-evergreen.js:185
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone-evergreen.js:559
Promise.then (async)
scheduleMicroTask @ zone-evergreen.js:542
scheduleTask @ zone-evergreen.js:381
scheduleTask @ zone-evergreen.js:211
scheduleMicroTask @ zone-evergreen.js:231
scheduleResolveOrReject @ zone-evergreen.js:845
then @ zone-evergreen.js:955
bootstrapModule @ core.js:40600
./src/main.ts @ main.ts:11
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:79
0 @ main.ts:12
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:79
checkDeferredModules @ bootstrap:45
webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap:32
(anonymous) @ main.js:1
client:52 [WDS] Live Reloading enabled.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below way

```
  myReactiveForm : FormGroup

fbForm(){
  this.myReactiveForm = this.fb.group({
    username: ['', Validators.nullValidator],
    email: ['', Validators.required],
    course: ['HTML', Validators.required],
    gender: ['female', Validators.required],
  });
}

 constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.fbForm()
 }
```

Comment: No...  I  was learning angualr formGroupName with Reactive form

Comment: Please help in that way only

Comment: formGroupName is mostly used with the form array. read this tutorial.

https://netbasal.com/angular-reactive-forms-the-ultimate-guide-to-formarray-3adbe6b0b61a